# What does `session.entropy_length` in `PHP.ini` do?

Tags: php, session, php-5.5, php-5.6

In the session section of `PHP.ini` there is a directive called `session.entropy_length`.

I'm aware that it's used to make the generation of the `session id` more random.

How does it do that?

What is the maximum length?

What if it's exceeding the bits of the `hash` in use?

Answer (score -2):

> session.entropy_length specifies the number of bytes which will be read from the file specified above. Defaults to 0 (disabled).

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.entropy-length)

The "file mentioned above" is session.entropy_file

'entropy' for sessions is related to the randomness of session id values

Comment: We know what's in the docs, but the docs aren't very helpful with this. I think the OP is trying to get more feeling for how to use it: What values make sense (aren't too large or too small)? How does the value relate to other settings like the hash type? What's a good value to use, and why wouldn't one use a higher value if it's allowed? Assuming the PHP team generally sets defaults for a reasonable level of security out-of-the-box, why is the default on this zero; isn't that a compromise of security?